# GELFAppender exception in weblogic JMS

Tags: java, logging, log4j, graylog

I am using graylog GELFAppender in my log4j.properties. 
In startup of application
this error occured:

```
    log4j:ERROR Error during sending GELF message. Error code: -1.
2016-02-03 12:02:47,513 ERROR [caspian.banking.router.DefaultErrorHandler:33] ERROR in MessageListener:
weblogic.jms.common.JMSException: weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherException: weblogic.rjvm.PeerGoneException: ; nested exception is: 
    weblogic.utils.net.SocketResetException
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.convertToJMSExceptionAndThrow(DispatcherAdapter.java:116)
    at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherAdapter.java:61)
    at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.receiveMessage(JMSSession.java:894)
    ....
java.io.IOException: An invalid argument was supplied
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramDispatcher.write(DatagramDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.write(DatagramChannelImpl.java:616)
    at org.graylog2.GelfUDPSender.sendDatagrams(GelfUDPSender.java:57)
    at org.graylog2.GelfUDPSender.sendMessage(GelfUDPSender.java:41)
    at org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender.append(GelfAppender.java:224)
    ... 
Caused by: weblogic.utils.net.SocketResetException
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocketOnce(SocketMuxer.java:931)
    at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.readReadySocket(SocketMuxer.java:887)
```

this is my log4j.properties file

```
## Graylog
log4j.appender.graylog2=org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender
log4j.appender.graylog2.graylogHost=192.168.243.23
#log4j.appender.graylog2.port=12201
log4j.appender.graylog2.originHost=localhost
log4j.appender.graylog2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.graylog2.additionalFields={'environment': 'DEV', 'application': 'lotus-core'}
log4j.appender.graylog2.extractStacktrace=true
log4j.appender.graylog2.addExtendedInformation=true
log4j.appender.graylog2.facility=lotus-core
log4j.appender.graylog2.Threshold=WARN
```

I googled and nothing found.
please help 
tnx